# Sapp BO - Agregate rows?

Tags: aggregate, business-objects

In Sapp Business Objects - Webintelligence document, putting my various dimension into a table result in something like this:

```
Week | ID | order | material A | material B|
 46  | 3  | 333   |  32432     |    0      |
 46  | 3  | 333   |    0       |   4935    |
```

But i want 1 row summing up the amount of each material pr unique Order number.

```
Week | ID | order | material A | material B|
 46  | 3  | 333   |  32432     |   4935    |
```

Answer (score 0):

If **material A** and **material B** were measures with **Sum** aggregation they would automatically add up.

Since they are dimensions you will need to create a variable like this...

```
=Sum([material A])
```

If **material A** is not a number you will need to convert it to a number first and then sum it up in your variable like this...

```
=Sum(ToNumber([material A]))
```

Whichever one works do the same for **material B**.